# Editing Slide Interval on JS Slideshow File

Tags: javascript, slideshow

Can someone tell me where I would actually set the interval between slides on this js file?

```
//This file is part of briaskISS.
//
//    briaskISS is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
//    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
//    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
//    (at your option) any later version.
//
//    briaskISS is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
//    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
//    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
//    GNU General Public License for more details.
//
//    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
//    along with briaskISS.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

function briaskISS(idModule, random, picInterval, transDelay, picArray)
{
    this.picRandom = random;
    this.picInterval = picInterval;
    this.transDelay = transDelay;
    this.picArray = picArray;

    this.curPic = 0;
    this.nextPic = 0;
    this.numPics = 0;
    this.curOpacity = 99
    this.nextOpacity = 0;

    this.idModule = idModule;

    this.initISS();
}

briaskISS.prototype.initISS=function()
{
    if (!document.getElementById || !document.createElement) return;

    this.picArray[0]
        = document.getElementById("briask-iss"+this.idModule).getElementsByTagName("img");

    this.numPics = this.picArray[0].length ;

    for(i = 0; i < this.picArray[0].length; i++)
        {
            this.picArray[0][i].opacity = 0;
            this.picArray[0][i].style.MozOpacity = .0;
            this.picArray[0][i].style.filter = "alpha(opacity=0)";
        }

    if (this.picRandom == 3)
    {
        this.issNextPic();
    }

    this.picArray[0][this.nextPic].style.display = "block";
    this.picArray[0][this.nextPic].style.opacity = .99;
    this.picArray[0][this.nextPic].style.MozOpacity = .99;
    this.picArray[0][this.nextPic].style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + (.99*100) + ")";

    this.curPic = this.nextPic;
    setTimeout("briaskInstance"+this.idModule+".issShow()", this.picInterval);
}

briaskISS.prototype.issShow=function()
{
    this.issNextPic();

    this.curOpacity = 100, this.nextOpacity = 0;

    setTimeout("briaskInstance"+this.idModule+".issTransition()", this.transDelay);
}

briaskISS.prototype.issNextPic=function()
{
    if (this.picRandom < 3)
    {
        if (this.curPic < (this.numPics - 1))
        {
            this.nextPic = this.curPic + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            this.nextPic = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            now = new Date();

            var rndPic = Math.ceil(this.numPics * Math.random(this.idModule)) - 1;

        }   while (this.curPic == rndPic)

        this.nextPic = rndPic;
    }
}

briaskISS.prototype.issTransition = function ()
{
    this.picArray[0][this.nextPic].style.display = "block";

    this.picArray[0][this.curPic].style.opacity = this.curOpacity/100;
    this.picArray[0][this.curPic].style.MozOpacity = this.curOpacity/100;
    this.picArray[0][this.curPic].style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + (this.curOpacity) + ")";

    this.picArray[0][this.nextPic].style.opacity = this.nextOpacity/100;
    this.picArray[0][this.nextPic].style.MozOpacity = this.nextOpacity/100;
    this.picArray[0][this.nextPic].style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + (this.nextOpacity) + ")";

    if (this.curOpacity > 0)
    {
        this.curOpacity -= 4;
        this.nextOpacity += 4;
        setTimeout("briaskInstance"+this.idModule+".issTransition()", this.transDelay);
    }
    else
    {
        this.picArray[0][this.curPic].style.display = "none";

        this.curPic = this.nextPic;
        setTimeout("briaskInstance"+this.idModule+".issShow()", this.picInterval);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying third parameter **picInterval**?

Comment: In the section with this.curPic = 0, etc., could I just add "this.picInterval = 5000"?

Comment: I don't see it actually declared anywhere, so I assume it's just a default value right now?